# Linux CentOS 6.0 - auto_eth0 not connecting

Tags: centos, linux, linux-networking, centos6

I just recently installed CentOS 6.0 i386 from the Live CD. However, now when I try to run updates, I do not have an internet connection.

I was told to run "system-config-services" and disable "NetworkManager" and enable "Network"

but it still doesn't work.

I configured everything to be setup as manual not automatic. 192.168.1.107 as ip 255.255.255.0 as net mask and 192.168.1.1 as gateway and dns.

What do you recommend?

Comment: From Paweł Brodacki:
 1. How do you connect to the Internet? Do you have a permanent IP address, or is it given by a DHCP server? What is your default gateway? What are DNS servers' addresses?

2. How many NICs do you have in the server? Are you sure you are configuring the correct one?

3. Did this connection ever work (e.g. during the install, or for a different machine)?

4. Does your ISP limit the number of machines you can connect? Do they monitor Ethernet cards MAC addresses? 

You really didn't give us much data to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend configuring eth0 with ifconfig if you really need it connected now.

Do you have multiple nics in that box?  Make sure the mac address for the nic you're using is the mac address listed in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.